# Getting results from one cell in SheetA when cell from SheetA and SheetB contain the same text

Tags: google-sheets

Here is what i'm having trouble with:

SheetA C7:C106 contains different names + some are empty
E7:E106 contains text that people choose from drop down list

Now in SheetB in cell D24 if cell C24 has the same text as any of the cells from SheetA C7:C106 it should show the text that is in E7:E106 in the same row.

for example:
in SheetB cell C24 has text "Dog", then formula in SheetB cell D24 should search for text "Dog" in SheetA C6:C106 (let's say it's C50) and show what's in E50 because of that.

Both sheets are in the same document.

Comment: Use `MATCH()` and `INDEX()`

Comment: What are we supposed to do if the text in C24 of SheetB occurs more than once in column C of SheetA? Also, is this for Excel or Google Sheets, or must it really work in both?

Comment: @JeremyKahan text in C7:C106 is unique in every cell, it will never be the same, it's only for Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by Gary's student, you need the following in your D cells of sheet b.

```
=iferror(index(SheetA!E$7:E$106,match(C24,SheetA!C$7:C$106,0)))
```

This example is for D24, but it can be dragged up or down.

EDIT: since you are using Google Sheets, you have this alternative, too.

```
=iferror(query(SheetA!C7:E106,"Select E where C='"&C24&"'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want this: **`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A); VLOOKUP(A2:A; 'Tab B'!A2:B; 2; 0); ))`**

which means that **`IF`** ID from **`Tab B`** is found in **`Tab A`**, formula will return **`2`** (second) column from range **`A:B`** of **`Tab B`** in sorted order based on IDs in **A** column of **`Tab A`** - hence that **`0`**

here is demo spreadsheet: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MUesMmT8JVTb_tqfaxfn38EWmDs_emByD8tBvZA_TKk/edit#gid=0)**

[image]